# using 'v-for' to build HTML select options and to assign key as the option value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the below HTML with Vue syntax:

```html
<select id='select-id' >
  <option selected disabled value=''>Select Option</option>
  <option v-for="(value, key) in object">{{ key }} - {{ value}}</option>
</select>
```

This builds my select with options from an object's key:value pairs. However, I want to assign the key as the options value:

```html
<select id='select-id' >
  <option selected disabled value=''>Select Option</option>
  <option v-for="(value, key) in object" value='{{ key }}'>{{ key }} - {{ value}}</option>
</select>
```

but this isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Template Syntax - Interpolations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)...

> #### Attributes

Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a [**v-bind directive**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

For example

```html
<option v-for="(value, key) in object" :value="key">
  {{ key }} - {{ value}}
</option>
```

---

Further reading:

- [Form Input Bindings - Basic Usage - Select](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)
- [Form Input Bindings - Value Bindings - Select Options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select-Options)

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Is this for all attributes? eg. :placeholder='key' ?

Comment: @AriVictor only for attributes where you want to use (ie _bind_) a variable value. Normal, static attributes like `placeholder="Enter text here"` are fine

Comment: i don't need key and object value, instead i need custom keys